# Nuget Packages Version difference analysis using powershell

Tags: powershell, nuget, nuget-package

In my solution, we use different versions of packages.However, I would now like to maintain a single version of a package through out the solution.

To analyze existing solution, I wrote powershell script to analyze all pacakges.config file recursively in a solution and I now have the PSObject which has the following content

```
Config                PackageName   Version
proj1\packages.config   A              4
proj1\packages.config   B              1
proj2\packages.config   A              4
proj2\packages.config   B              1
proj3\packages.config   A              3
proj3\packages.config   B              1
```

In this output there are 2 packages A and B,where package A has different versions and B has same version throughout.

Now I need to show only the packages that has different versions in the following format.The package B which has the same version throughout should be removed from output.

```
PackageName Version Config
A             4     proj1\packages.config
A             4     proj2\packages.config
A             3     proj3\packages.config
```

How do I do that ? I tried group by PackageName , but I could not find a way to remove the package B which has the same version through out.

**Update:**

Complete powershell script to find conflicting package version and its usage can be found [here](https://codinginbliss.wordpress.com/2014/12/22/manage-consistent-nuget-package-version-through-out-c-solution/)

Comment: So in your data Package B version 1 is the master? Is that manually determined by you? Then any package that is not pBv1 you would want to show? I feel that I don't understand since this would appear very easy? Is it like Micky suggested? Ommitting any version that is not in package B? Could package B have more than one version?

Comment: @Matt: PackageB is something like AutoFac assembly. An Autofac assembly for a particular project can only have one version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it in the following way

```
$groupedPackgeList = GetPackages | Group-Object -Property PackageName
$multipleVersionPackageList = @()
$groupedPackgeList | % {
    $originalCount =$_.Count
    $groupByVersion = $_.Group | Group-Object -Property Version
    if($groupByVersion.Count -ne $originalCount)
    {
        $packageName = $_.Name
        $groupByVersion |% {
            $_.Group |% {
            $tempObj = New-Object PSCustomObject  -Property @{Id=$packageName;Version=$_.Version;Config=$_.Config;}    
            $multipleVersionPackageList+=$tempObj  
            }
        } 
    }
}
$multipleVersionPackageList
```

Comment: This is similar to what I would have done. Good Work!

Answer (score 2):

There is probably an easier way to do this, but I could not find it.
Issue is that we need to find all the packages with various versions, and save those, while ignoring packages that have a consistent version number.

I started by regenerating the PSCustomObject array `$a` from your example, so we have something we can work with:

```
$a = @()

$a += New-Object PSCustomObject -Property @{
        Config = "proj1\packages.config";
        PackageName = "A";
        Version = 4
    }
$a += New-Object PSCustomObject -Property @{
        Config = "proj1\packages.config";
        PackageName = "B";
        Version = 1
    }
$a += New-Object PSCustomObject -Property @{
        Config = "proj1\packages.config";
        PackageName = "A";
        Version = 4
    }
$a += New-Object PSCustomObject -Property @{
        Config = "proj1\packages.config";
        PackageName = "B";
        Version = 1
    }
$a += New-Object PSCustomObject -Property @{
        Config = "proj1\packages.config";
        PackageName = "A";
        Version = 3
    }
$a += New-Object PSCustomObject -Property @{
        Config = "proj1\packages.config";
        PackageName = "B";
        Version = 1
    }
```

We will then save the results in a new array called `$b`

```
$b = @()
```

We are then going through each element in the `$a` array.
If this element is not found in `$b`, we are going to analyze it.
We compare the package name and version of this element with all the elements in `$a` looking for a different version number.
If we find a match, we save all the elements with the same PackageName in $b.

```
$a | % { 
    $found = $false
    foreach ($e in $b)
    {
        if ($e.PackageName -eq $_.PackageName)
        {
            $found = $true
            break
        }
    }
    if (!$found)
    {
        foreach ($i in $a)
        {
            if ($i.PackageName -eq $_.PackageName -and $i.Version -ne $_.Version)
            {
                foreach ($j in $a)
                {
                    if ($j.PackageName -eq $_.PackageName)
                    {
                        $b += $j                    
                    }
                }
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result then is:

```
Config                PackageName                       Version
------                -----------                       -------
proj1\packages.config A                                       4
proj1\packages.config A                                       4
proj1\packages.config A                                       3
```